# why kaltura-red5 can't run after yum install?

Tags: red5, kaltura

after I run yum install kaltura-red5 completely,i can't find the port 5080 when i run netstat -an.The next step Request http://hostname:5080 is error
how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: edit the local.ini file of kaltura and set the rtmp url to red5 server url.

```
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"> vi /opt/kaltura/app/configurations/local.ini </span>
```

Step-2: make a soft link of kaltura entry to red5 streams

```
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">ln -s /opt/kaltura/web/content /usr/lib/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/ </span>
```

Step-3: Add a delivery profile

go to admin_console, publishers profiles drop down list select delivery profile.
From type drop down list select RTMP and click on create?

Fill up the required box,
?Delivery profile name*:  any name
Delivery profile Type*: Choose LOCAL_PATH_RTMP
Streamer Type*: Choose RTMP
Supported Media Protocols: Enter rtmp,rtmpe,rtmpt,rtmpte

Delivery profile URL*: Here enter red5 server url with port number 1935 for example rtmp://:1935/oflaDemo
now save

Step-4: Now to active the added delivery profile

from admin_console, publishers action drop down list select “Configure”.
In Publisher Specific Delivery Settings , from Add Format drop down list select RTMP and click on ADD.

In Options, select your created delivery profile, and click OK.
now Save.
you  have done, Now check the RTMP streaming preview.

If You have any Issue then once run red5 configuration and kaltura configuration.

```
/opt/kaltura/bin/kaltura-config-all.sh
/opt/kaltura/bin/kaltura-red5-config.sh
```